# SDL_Init fails on linuxbrew while system wide version works

Tags: sdl-2, linuxbrew

I am using `linuxbrew` to install dynamic libraries without `sudo`. Those libraries are needed to compile run the project.

For some reason I need to `brew uninstall sdl2 --ignore-dependencies` in order to init SDL2 successfuly using system-wide version (I'd like to not depend on it though).

There are minor version differences `2.0.5 vs 2.0.2+dfsg1-6` but I think it's unlikely the root cause (the older one works).

How can I enable SDL2 from `linuxbrew`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile SDL2 with X11 support: `brew edit sdl2` or apply this patch directly:

```
diff --git a/Formula/sdl2.rb b/Formula/sdl2.rb
index 7450e40..70d42ee 100644
--- a/Formula/sdl2.rb
+++ b/Formula/sdl2.rb
@@ -45,7 +45,7 @@ class Sdl2 < Formula
     if ENV.compiler == :llvm || (ENV.compiler == :clang && DevelopmentTools.clang_build_version < 421)
       args << "--disable-assembly"
     end
-    args << "--without-x"
+    args << "--with-x11"
     args << "--disable-haptic" << "--disable-joystick" if MacOS.version <= :snow_leopard

     system "./configure", *args
d
```